# FFMPEG: flac audio file duration in metadata is 0

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, metadata, flac

I have a flac audio file with incorrect duration in the metadata. The audio has a length of 55 minutes but the metadata has a duration of 0. Is it possible to use an ffmpeg command to fix this?

Below are the outputs of an ffprobe:

```
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
```

Comment: FLAC usually doesn't have a duration in the metadata. You can work out the duration from the sample count and sample rate in the StreamInfo metadata block.

Comment: hi @greg-449, all my other FLAC files have durations. Do you know of a way I could get the calculated duration into the metadata?

Comment: Try re-muxing: `ffmpeg -i input.flac -map 0 -c copy output.flac`

Comment: hi @llogan, the duration of output.flac is still N/A after the re-muxing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The FLAC header is missing or incomplete. Re-encoding will re-write it:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -c:v copy -c:a flac output.flac
```

There will be no quality loss as FLAC is lossless.

Comment: For searchability: this ffmpeg fixed a broken flac file I had which `flac` itself could not fix. `flac` said: "ERROR: FLAC input has STREAMINFO with unknown total samples which is not supported"